Pandas groupby transform mean with date before current row for huge dataframe
I have a Pandas dataframe that looks like
df = pd.DataFrame([['John', 'A', '1/1/2017', '10'],
                   ['John', 'A', '2/2/2017', '15'],
                   ['John', 'A', '2/2/2017', '20'],
                   ['John', 'A', '3/3/2017', '30'],
                   ['Sue', 'B', '1/1/2017', '10'],
                   ['Sue', 'B', '2/2/2017', '15'],
                   ['Sue', 'B', '3/2/2017', '20'],
                   ['Sue', 'B', '3/3/2017', '7'],
                   ['Sue', 'B', '4/4/2017', '20']],
                  columns=['Customer', 'Group', 'Deposit_Date', 'DPD'])

And I want to create a new row called PreviousMean. This column is the year to date average of DPD for that customer. i.e. Includes all DPDs up to but not including rows that match the current deposit date. If no previous records existed then it's null or 0.
So the desired outcome looks like
  Customer  Group  Deposit_Date  DPD  PreviousMean
0     John      A    2017-01-01   10           NaN
1     John      A    2017-02-02   15          10.0
2     John      A    2017-02-02   20          10.0
3     John      A    2017-03-03   30          15.0
4      Sue      B    2017-01-01   10           NaN
5      Sue      B    2017-02-02   15          10.0
6      Sue      B    2017-03-02   20          12.5
7      Sue      B    2017-03-03    7          15.0
8      Sue      B    2017-04-04   20          13.0

And after some researching on the site and internet here is one solution:
df['PreviousMean'] = df.apply(
    lambda x: df[(df.Customer == x.Customer) & 
                 (df.Group == x.Group) & 
                 (df.Deposit_Date < x.Deposit_Date)].DPD.mean(), 
axis=1)

And it works fine. However, my actual dataframe is much larger (~1 million rows) and the above code is very slow.
I have asked a similar question before: Pandas groupby transform mean with date before current row for huge huge dataframe
except that this time the groupby is done on two columns and hence the solutions do not work and I failed to try to generalize it.
Is there any better way to do it? Thanks

The linked solution works fine, but you have to carefully add all the groups in groupby and then remove the matching levels in droplevel:
df['Deposit_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Deposit_Date'])

groups = ['Customer', 'Group']

df['PreviousMean'] = (df.groupby(groups)
                        .apply(lambda s: s['DPD'].expanding().mean().shift()
                                                 .mask(s['Deposit_Date'].duplicated())
                                                 .ffill(),
                               include_groups=False)
                        .droplevel(groups)
                     )

Output:
  Customer Group Deposit_Date  DPD  PreviousMean
0     John     A   2017-01-01   10           NaN
1     John     A   2017-02-02   15          10.0
2     John     A   2017-02-02   20          10.0
3     John     A   2017-03-03   30          15.0
4      Sue     B   2017-01-01   10           NaN
5      Sue     B   2017-02-02   15          10.0
6      Sue     B   2017-03-02   20          12.5
7      Sue     B   2017-03-03    7          15.0
8      Sue     B   2017-04-04   20          13.0


import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame([['John', 'A', '1/1/2017', '10'],
                   ['John', 'A', '2/2/2017', '15'],
                   ['John', 'A', '2/2/2017', '20'],
                   ['John', 'A', '3/3/2017', '30'],
                   ['Sue', 'B', '1/1/2017', '10'],
                   ['Sue', 'B', '2/2/2017', '15'],
                   ['Sue', 'B', '3/2/2017', '20'],
                   ['Sue', 'B', '3/3/2017', '7'],
                   ['Sue', 'B', '4/4/2017', '20']],
                  columns=['Customer', 'Group', 'Deposit_Date', 'DPD'])


df['Deposit_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Deposit_Date'])
df['DPD'] = pd.to_numeric(df['DPD'])

df['Previous_mean'] = df.groupby('Customer')['DPD'].expanding().mean()\
.shift().reset_index(level =0,drop=True)\
.mask(df['Deposit_Date'].duplicated()).ffill()

df.loc[df.groupby('Customer').head(1).index,'Previous_mean'] = np.nan
print(df)

'''
  Customer Group Deposit_Date  DPD  Previous_mean
0     John     A   2017-01-01   10            NaN
1     John     A   2017-02-02   15           10.0
2     John     A   2017-02-02   20           10.0
3     John     A   2017-03-03   30           15.0
4      Sue     B   2017-01-01   10            NaN
5      Sue     B   2017-02-02   15           15.0
6      Sue     B   2017-03-02   20           12.5
7      Sue     B   2017-03-03    7           12.5
8      Sue     B   2017-04-04   20           13.0
'''

expanding() and groupby() are powerful but can be slower on large datasets as they recalculate means for every row.Hence, please check the following technique.
Method 2(efficient) :
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame([['John', 'A', '1/1/2017', '10'],
                   ['John', 'A', '2/2/2017', '15'],
                   ['John', 'A', '2/2/2017', '20'],
                   ['John', 'A', '3/3/2017', '30'],
                   ['Sue', 'B', '1/1/2017', '10'],
                   ['Sue', 'B', '2/2/2017', '15'],
                   ['Sue', 'B', '3/2/2017', '20'],
                   ['Sue', 'B', '3/3/2017', '7'],
                   ['Sue', 'B', '4/4/2017', '20']],
                  columns=['Customer', 'Group', 'Deposit_Date', 'DPD'])

df['Deposit_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Deposit_Date'])
df['DPD'] = pd.to_numeric(df['DPD'])

df['Cumulative_sum'] = df.groupby('Customer')['DPD'].cumsum() - df['DPD']
df['Cumulative_count'] = df.groupby('Customer').cumcount()

df['Previous_mean'] = df['Cumulative_sum'] /df['Cumulative_count'] 

df['Previous_mean'] = df['Previous_mean'].mask(df['Deposit_Date'].duplicated()).ffill() 

df.loc[df.groupby('Customer').head(1).index,'Previous_mean'] = np.nan
print(df.to_string())
'''
  Customer Group Deposit_Date  DPD  Cumulative_sum  Cumulative_count  Previous_mean
0     John     A   2017-01-01   10               0                 0            NaN
1     John     A   2017-02-02   15              10                 1           10.0
2     John     A   2017-02-02   20              25                 2           10.0
3     John     A   2017-03-03   30              45                 3           15.0
4      Sue     B   2017-01-01   10               0                 0            NaN
5      Sue     B   2017-02-02   15              10                 1           15.0
6      Sue     B   2017-03-02   20              25                 2           12.5
7      Sue     B   2017-03-03    7              45                 3           12.5
8      Sue     B   2017-04-04   20              52                 4           13.0
'''

